# Find in array of objects with arrays using objection.js and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I need support to solve the following, I am using `objection.js` with `Postgresql` 14.5 and node.js, I have a table called articles with a JSON column called properties.

the jsonb properties column is structured as follows:

```
{
  characteristics: [
    {
      attributes: [
        {
          name: '<string text>',
          attribute_id: '<id value>',
          attribute_value: '<string text>', // < ----- string text
        },
      ],
      specification_id: '<id value>',
    },
    {
      attributes: [
        {
          attribute_value: 30, // < ----- int number
        },
      ],
      specification_id: '<id value>',
    },
  ],
}
```

the query is for attributes[any position] .attribute_value where is int number

I need to do an or Where query, where specification_id is equal to the id I assign to it; and attributes.attribute_value is less than X number that I assign to it.
written example:
specification_id: '12e8de7a-5dd8-4614-bd56-e6335d216ea1'
and attributes.attribute_value < 30

and I need to do another or Where query, where specification_id is equal to the id I assign to it; and attributes.attribute_value is greater than X number that I assign
written example:
specification_id: '12e8de7a-5dd8-4614-bd56-e6335d216ea1'
and attributes.attribute_value > 30

and I need to do another or Where query, where specification_id is equal to the id I assign to it; and attributes.attribute_value is greater than or equal to X number that I assign to it, or less than or equal to X number that I assign to it.
written example:
specification_id: '12e8de7a-5dd8-4614-bd56-e6335d216ea1'
and (attributes.attribute_value >= 25 and attributes.attribute_value <= 31)

I hope I have explained myself, an apology for my bad English.